# Why are these libraries incompatible with my virtual environment in Python 3.9

Tags: python, pandas, pip, virtualenv, python-3.9

I'm trying to run Python with a virtual environment and the code is written in 2020 so I'm using Python 3.9 in the virtual environment. I was able to get that running properly and here is the requirements file

[image]

when I try to install requirements it gets stuck at installing pandas and there's a big error message

[image]

[image]

at first I thought it was an issue with versions but pandas 2.2.0 is perfectly compatible with Python 3.9

[image]

has anybody ever seen an error like this before and could potentially provide some insight?
Thank you very much

Comment: Please post text as text, not images.